# Determine given module is rails engine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

Hi I have two modules

1. Admin
2. Blog (Blog is a rails engine)
   where Admin is a module for namespacing admin features of app, but Blog is a module representing rails engine. Is there a better way to determine which among them is engine, like a function "is_engine?"

> Admin.is_engine?
>
> => false
>
> Blog.is_engine?
>
> => true

Definately I can have a try catch thing to determine this

```
def is_engine? module
  module::Engine
  true
rescue NameError
  false
end
```

here

```
is_engine? Admin
```

will return false

```
is_engine? Blog
```

will return true

Thanks

Comment: <http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html> Here is the link Documentation for rails engine, it might be helpful to you. According to your purpose you will have to use methods provided for the same.

Comment: a rails engine is a class, not a module.

Comment: @SumitMunot Please see edits in question.

Comment: @giorgian Please see edits in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do: a Rails Engine is a class  (a subclass of `Rails::Engine`), not a module.

If you have an **instance**,  you could use:

```
admin.kind_of?(Rails::Engine)
```

If you have a **class**, you can use:

```
Something.ancestors.include?(Rails::Engine)
```

If what you have is a module, then it cannot be a subclass of Rails::Engine, and it's not an engine.

## EDIT

If you have a module or constant `something` and want to know if there's a constant with a certain name in its namespace, you can use:

```
something.constants.include?(:Engine)
```